# Why is there white space showing between the articles

Tags: css

I thought I was good at CSS but I just can't figure out why there is white space showing in between the posts. Do you?

http://www.casinobuzz.info/casino-games-archive/

Comment: What posts do you mean?

Comment: Because that's the page I'm working on at the moment. It's not spam. I can remove the link later.

Comment: @Eduardo Look under the dracula game

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] reproducing the issue. The code that you include ***in your question*** must be ***Minimal*** (only the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing more), ***Complete*** (all of the code necessary to reproduce the issue, nothing less) and ***Verifiable*** (we should be able to reproduce the issue using the code ***in your question*** alone, nothing more and nothing less). Without this, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the elements have a variable heigth, so

```
article {
    float: left;
}
```

doesn't work very well.

If you reset your float every second element (the last post in a row), the white space is removed.

Try adding:

```
article:nth-child(even) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer with the code ***in the question***. We don't want these questions to get answered until the question is edited to fit within the guidelines of this site. Otherwise, it teaches users that it is OK to post questions like these, because even if they get closed, they still get their answer. Questions need to be on-topic to get answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Somehow I exactly knew what he meant, **and** I solved his problem, not that impossible, right? I agree though on most you say. But how could OP know? At least he got his answer, and he can ask it the right way next time, or maybe format his question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how else more to put it. I could have made a fiddle but that would have taken a lot more unnecessary time. CSS is more a case of either "you know it or you don't" I don't specialize in CSS. Asking the question this way, I learned something from the community and I appreciate your time very much.

Comment: The problem is that he won't ask it the right way next time because instead of teaching him how to fish, you gave him a fish. Now the question is still extremely off-topic for Stack Overflow, and does not fit within the guide lines at all. What you've actually done here is contribute to the problem instead of the solution. For those of us actively trying to keep Stack Overflow on-topic and high-quality, it is very disheartening to see other users blatantly disregarding the site rules and giving them exactly what should not be given unless the question is in turn made on-topic.

Comment: Think for a second about what is going to happen if the link goes dead, or the code at the link is changed? This whole Q&A will be completely useless to anyone other than the OP ever again, and that is not what we are trying to do here. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of useful solutions to common programming problems for programmers everywhere. It is not, contrary to popular belief, a help-desk where our sole purpose is to help the OP and nothing more, which is what you have succeeded in doing here.

Comment: @emporio Next time, please read [ask] and visit the [help/on-topic] before posting a question here and make sure that you include all of the necessary information to solve the problem ***in your question*** so that the question can be useful to someone other than just you.

Comment: If you put it like that, I can only agree. But I learned the hard way too with my first question(s), yet I didn't feel like I shouldv'e been denied a proper answer (too) at the time. Actually, I've never thought that OP's question disregarded the site rules either when I tried to answer. I'll try to pay more attention next time.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the feedback! Will do that next time.